# NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData changes field type

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsstring, nsdictionary, nsdata

I'm getting the following JSON response from the server:

```
{
   "userId":"123456789",
   "displayName":"display name"
}
```

When I use `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` and then prints the result `NSDictionary` I see in the console the following:

> userId = 123456789
>   displayName = "display name"

Why do `JSONObjectWithData` changes the `userId` field type from String to a number?

Comment: It doesn't. It's just a representation when printed in the console. The fields are still String if you check their types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. The JSON deserialisation respects the data type and will maintain it. You can't tell the data type from a simple description log, you need to actually interrogate the class. The description log will quote some things if it makes more sense for the human reader, like spaces in the description, but it also omits quotes in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.

Don't infer a variable type from its log representation, just test. Fire a Playground with this, for example:

```
let str = "{\"userId\":\"123456789\",\"displayName\":\"display name\"}"
if let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    jsonResult = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []),
    jsonObject = jsonResult as? [String:String],
    id = jsonObject["userId"] {
        print("User ID is " + id)
}
```